# Help with making a multi-component tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to make a tikz figure for my project. I am able to start and understand the concepts with online help. Although I am not able to make the complete figure, can someone help me with this.

The images of cat and sound wave can be imported from a .png file . <cat.png and sound.png>

I have already made this figure in draw.io tool which can be accesed as: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAosM9aPTPQY9G3w2cVeMdl6LYa_HhvP/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

**My try:**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=Stealth,
  encoder/.style={
    draw, 
    fill=gray!20, 
    trapezium,
    trapezium left angle=70, 
    trapezium right angle=70,
    minimum height=2cm, 
    minimum width=1cm,
    text width=2.5cm,
    align=center,
    inner xsep=0pt
  },
  label/.style={
    align=left
  },
  vector/.style={
    draw,
    minimum height=1cm,
    minimum width=1cm,
    fill=#1,
    text centered
  }
]

% Text Encoder block
\node[encoder] (encoder) at (10,0) {Text Encoder};

% Labels for sound descriptions
\node[label] (label1) at (0,1) {1 : The sound of dog};
\node[label] (label2) at (0,0) {2 : The sound of cat};
\node[label] (label3) at (0,-1) {3 : The sound of rain};
\node[label] (label4) at (0,-2) {4 : The sound of thunder};

% Lines from labels to Text Encoder
\draw[->] (label1.east) -- (label1-|encoder.west);
\draw[->] (label2.east) -- (label2-|encoder.west);
\draw[->] (label3.east) -- (label3-|encoder.west);
\draw[->] (label4.east) -- (label4-|encoder.west);

% Colored vectors (T1 to T4)
\node[vector=blue!30] (T1) at ([shift={(1cm,0.5cm)}]encoder.east) {T1};
\node[vector=green!30, below=0 of T1] (T2) {T2};
\node[vector=yellow!30, below=0 of T2] (T3) {T3};
\node[vector=orange!30, below=0 of T3] (T4) {T4};

% Arrow from Text Encoder to T1-T4
\draw[->] (encoder.east) -- (T1.west |- encoder.east);
\draw[->] (encoder.east) -- (T2.west |- encoder.east);
\draw[->] (encoder.east) -- (T3.west |- encoder.east);
\draw[->] (encoder.east) -- (T4.west |- encoder.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of suggesting image downloads (of a cat and sound wave), just use generic images provided by the [`mwe` package](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe). They are available with all (La)TeX distributions

Comment: @Werner Hi, I can manage the figure of cat and wave.

Comment: Yes, YOU can. It's easier for the community to not have to download content from external links. You came here for help, so consider making things easy for the community by using generic content whenever possible (like images from [`mwe`](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe), text from [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)/[`kantlipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/kantlipsum) or larger document structures using [`blinddocument`](//ctan.org/pkg/blinddocument)); that's the request.

Comment: Anyway, it seems all you need is to put `\includgraphics` into a TikZ node.

Comment: You can use scopes to align different things using `[shift={(x,y)}]`.  (The braces are to keep the parser from noticing the comma.)

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thanks for the note @Werner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, I just wanted to do the cat, which the OP doesn't even want. But I did the bits the OP wanted help with, too, so the cat seems fair enough.

The result depends on the Ti*k*Z libraries available when compiled. So you may get a stripy marmalade cat ...

[image: stripy marmalade cat]

... or you may get a lucky black cat ...

[image: lucky black cat]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703854/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Formal_that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703831/
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric,shapes.multipart,matrix,calc,ext.paths.ortho}
\newif\ifcathod
\cathodfalse
\IfFileExists{tikzlibrarycathod.code.tex}{\usetikzlibrary{cathod}\cathodtrue}{\usetikzlibrary{tikzlings}}
\newdimen\tempdima
\newdimen\tempdimb
\newdimen\tempdimc
\newlength\templengtha
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=Stealth,
    every node/.style={font=\sffamily},
    encoder/.style={
      draw, 
      fill=gray!20, 
      trapezium,
      trapezium left angle=70, 
      trapezium right angle=70,
      align=center,
      inner xsep=0pt,
      rotate=-90,
    },
    label/.style={
      align=left
    },
    vector/.style={
      draw,
      minimum height=1cm,
      minimum width=1cm,
      fill=#1,
      text centered
    },
    AT/.style={inner ysep=20pt,draw=black},
  ]
  
  \matrix (snds) [matrix of nodes,every node/.append style={anchor=base west}] 
  {
    1 & : & The sound of a dog\\
    2 & : & The sound of a cat\\
    3 & : & The sound of rain\\
    4 & : & The sound of thunder\\
  };
  
  % Text Encoder block
  \node [encoder,right=of snds.east,anchor=south] (encoder)  {Text\\Encoder};
  
  % Colored vectors (T1 to T4)
  \node (T) [rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,AT,below right=20pt and 60pt of encoder.north east,anchor=north west,rectangle split part fill={blue!30,green!30,yellow!30,orange!30},rectangle split part align={base}] { T1 \nodepart{two} T2 \nodepart{three} T3 \nodepart{four} T4};
  
  \node [encoder,below=20pt of encoder |- T.south,anchor=west] (enc)  {Audio\\Encoder};
  
  \node (a1) [AT,fill=red!30,anchor=west] at (enc.center -| {$(enc.north)!.5!(T.west)$}) {A1};
  
  \path (T.west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\tempdima}{\tempdimb}
  \path (T.east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\tempdimb}{\tempdimc}
  
  \pgfmathsetlength \templengtha{(((\tempdimb-\tempdima)/4)-height("X")-0.8pt)/2}

  \node (a) [inner ysep=\templengtha,rectangle split,rectangle split part fill={gray!30,gray!30,blue!50!gray!30,gray!30},rotate=-90,draw=black] at (T.center |- enc.center) { AAAA \nodepart{two} AAAA \nodepart{three} AAAA \nodepart{four} AAAA};
  
  \ifcathod \path ([yshift=20pt]snds-3-3.east |- enc.west) pic {cath eistedd={enw=cat,maint=1mm,stripiau=orange!50!brown,llenwi=orange!50!brown!50!white,lliw=brown}}  ;
  \else \path ([yshift=20pt]snds-3-3.east |- enc.south) pic [scale=.5]  {cat};
  \fi
  
  % Arrow from Text Encoder to T1-T4
  \draw[->] (encoder.north) -| (T.north);
  \foreach \i in {north east,south east}\draw [->,rounded corners] (snds.\i) -|- (encoder.south);
  \draw (enc.north) [->] -- (a1.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate that a lot! Thanks. The cat looks OG.

Comment: @Formal_that Excuse my ignorance, but what's 'OG'? Outrageously Grotesque or Obviously Gorgeous?

Comment: Sure, actually it's not something which is expected to be know. The term is "Original Gangster" .

Comment: @Formal_that Thanks.